# SQL syntax error

Tags: sql, delphi, ado, tadoquery

I want to run a simple SQL from Delphi 2007.

I use `AdoQuery`. My table has a column `id` and data type is `int` (autoincrement).

My question is if I execute

```
select * from comlist
```

there is no problem, it runs. But if I define a field on SQL like

```
select compname from comlist
```

Delphi complains

> ado:Field 'id' not found

The `Compname` column exist in table.

I have the following fields on my table:

```
id int
creationdate datetime
compid nvarcahr(50)
complocation nvarchar(50)
serial nvarchar(50) 
compname nvarchar(50)
```

I have error with this code:

```
ado.Close;
ado.SQL.Clear;
ado.SQL.Add('SELECT   compname  FROM comlist');
ado.Open;
```

I have no error with this code:

```
ado.Close;
ado.SQL.Clear;
ado.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM comlist');
ado.Open;
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Please double check from table definition, the spelling of column(compname) you specifying in select query.

Comment: Hi but I get this error whatever I write as column. for ex tried with other columns like compid or complocation. but result is same

Comment: Please, show us the **structure** of that `comlist` table! What columns, what datatypes?

Comment: can you output a sample of results of `SELECT * FROM comlist`?

Comment: This looks bogus. You ask for compname but the error names id.

Comment: id  int 
creationdate  datetime
compid  nvarcahr(50)
complocation nvarchar(50)
serial  nvarchar(50)
compname nvarchar(50)

I have only these fields on my table.

Comment: SELECT * FROM comlist runs stable, I can not use a field

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: @HakanSubaşı yes we understand your issue, however by providing actual output from your code it gives everyone better understanding of what is being returned. It might even be a simple case of you are connecting to the wrong DB for example which happens to have the same named Table which is why `SELECT *` works and `SELECT [specific column]` doesnt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might have fields defined in your query component.
Select ADOQuery component and open Fields editor from context menu and remove fields.

Comment: +1 My thoughts exactly. (persistent fields defined in design mode)

Comment: I dont understand why it happen (Becasue I use all field on field editor for every query ) but your suggestion solved my problem

Comment: @HakanSubaşı The error is because the fields in the field editor are the ones your ADOQuery ***expects*** to get back from the database. But since you changed your query, those fields are no longer returned by the database.